# QueryBuilders array Elastic search 2.4

Tags: elasticsearch

```
 QueryBuilder missingFiletr = QueryHelper.andQuery(incCatsEmptyFilter, excCatsEmptyFilter, incEmptyFilter, excEmptyFilter);
```

I am calling andQuery method and all the parameters of **andFilterBuilders**()
are going to **filterBuilders** array nad now I am extracting this into **filterBuilder** as i want to ***and*** all the queryBuilders. Is it correct format

```
public static QueryBuilder andQuery(QueryBuilder... filterBuilders) {
QueryBuilder filterBuilder = null;

if (filterBuilders != null && filterBuilders.length > 0) {

  for(int i = 0 ; i < filterBuilders.length ; i++){
    filterBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(filterBuilders[i]);
  }

}
return filterBuilder;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are creating a new `bool/filter` query on each iteration and reassigning it to the same variable, that won't work. You need to do it like this instead:

```
public static QueryBuilder andQuery(QueryBuilder... filterBuilders) {
  BoolQueryBuilder filterBuilder = null;

  if (filterBuilders != null && filterBuilders.length > 0) {
    // create the bool query here
    filterBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();    

    for(QueryBuilder filter : filterBuilders){
      // add each filter to the bool query here
      filterBuilder.filter(filter);
    }

  }
  return filterBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Now it showing error  for(int i = 0 ; i < filterBuilders.length ; i++){
    // add each filter to the bool query here
    filterBuilder.filter(filterBuilders[i]);
  }  error on   .filter() as after filterBuilder it is not showing any filter method

Comment: filterBuilder = QueryBuilders.andQuery(filterBuilders);  I just want to replace this line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41595253/searchrequestbuilder-elastic-saecrh-2-4